# Solve $xy\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{x^2 - y^2 - x^2y^2 - 1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone please help me solving the below
$$
xy\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{x^2 - y^2 - x^2y^2 - 1}
$$
If there would have been + instead of -, It would have been easier.
I tried 2 ways as mentioned below :
1. Putting $x^2 = u, y^2 = v$
2. Squaring both sides.Then, dividing both sides by $x^2y^2$
But didn't able to go much further.

Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried?

Comment: @Alain, Edited. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Maple does not find a closed-form solution. That's a pretty good indication that there may not be closed-form solutions.  Do you have any reason to believe there should be one?  Of course you can try numerical or series solutions.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a sign error? If even one more $-$ had been a $+$, it would be possible to separate variables, not matter which of the signs changed.

Comment: @Paul, I also thought the same. But, It's a question asked in UPSC CSE 2005. Most probably, It's correct.

Comment: I'm thinking a trig substitution may be helpful. For example, for everything to remain real, you need to have $-1 \le y \le 1$, and $x^2 \ge \dfrac{1+y^2}{1-y^2}$, which has the form of a known trig formula - though with $y = \tan \theta$, going against the obvious choices meeting the limits on $y$. But I don't have time to follow that thought further.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $u=x^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{du}\dfrac{du}{dx}=2x\dfrac{dy}{du}$

$\therefore2x^2y\dfrac{dy}{du}=\sqrt{u-y^2-uy^2-1}$

$2uy\dfrac{dy}{du}=\sqrt{u-y^2-uy^2-1}$

Let $v=y^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{du}=2y\dfrac{dy}{du}$

$\therefore u\dfrac{dv}{du}=\sqrt{u-v-uv-1}$

Let $w=\sqrt{u-v-uv-1}$ ,

Then $w^2=u-1-(u+1)v$

$v=\dfrac{u-1}{u+1}-\dfrac{w^2}{u+1}$

$\dfrac{dv}{du}=\dfrac{2}{(u+1)^2}+\dfrac{w^2}{(u+1)^2}-\dfrac{2w}{u+1}\dfrac{dw}{du}$

$\therefore\dfrac{2u}{(u+1)^2}+\dfrac{uw^2}{(u+1)^2}-\dfrac{2uw}{u+1}\dfrac{dw}{du}=w$

$\dfrac{2uw}{u+1}\dfrac{dw}{du}=\dfrac{uw^2}{(u+1)^2}-w+\dfrac{2u}{(u+1)^2}$

$w\dfrac{dw}{du}=\dfrac{w^2}{2(u+1)}-\dfrac{(u+1)w}{2u}+\dfrac{1}{u+1}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Comment: Till here, I had also done. How to proceed further? How to separate the 2 variables w and z?